# Gap created UITableView where no section header or footer should be shown

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a gap that is created between two sections and I don't know how to get rid of it.

I have 4 sections:

- Section 1(Lifelist),
- 2(Dawn chorus), and
- 3(Search)
- 4(Birds)

Section 1, 2, and 3 all have (same type) headers, but section 4 doesn't. Section 1, 2, and 4 have footers, but 3 doesn't.

On app load, there is a gap created between section 3 and 4 where there is no header & footer. I've tried to prevent this through the following code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerIdentifier = HomeViewSectionHeaderView.reuseIdentifier
        guard let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(
                withIdentifier: headerIdentifier)
                as? HomeViewSectionHeaderView
        else {
            return nil
        }
        if !sections[section].showSectionHeader {
            return nil
        }
        
        view.textLabel?.text = sections[section].title
        
        
        return view
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(
                withIdentifier: HomeViewSectionFooterView.reuseIdentifier)
                as? HomeViewSectionFooterView
        else {
            return nil
        }
        if !sections[section].showSectionFooter {
            return nil
        }
        
        return view
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if (sections[section].showSectionHeader){
            return 50.0
        }
        return 0.0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if (sections[section].showSectionHeader){
            return 50.0
        }
        return 0.0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if (sections[section].showSectionFooter){
            return 8.0
        }
        return 0.0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if (sections[section].showSectionFooter){
            return 8.0
        }
        return 0.0
    }
```

On the view hierarchy we can clearly see it is a gap without any elements:
[image: View hierarchy]

The full screen looks like this:
[image: Full screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning **0** to  `heightForFooterInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection` try returning a non zero value (close to 0 of course) like `0.001` or `.leastNormalMagnitude` or `.leastNonzeroMagnitude`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if (sections[section].showSectionFooter){
            return 8.0
        }
        return .leastNormalMagnitude //or you can use .leastNonzeroMagnitude or return a non zero value like 0.001
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if (sections[section].showSectionHeader){
            return 50.0
        }
        return .leastNormalMagnitude //or you can use .leastNonzeroMagnitude or return a non zero value like 0.001
}
```

Comment: Had to do it for headers as well (I recommend changing the answer to include that as well). Worked! I tried it before, but I guess back then I had other issues that have now been cleaned up.

Comment: @stephan: Am glad it worked :)

Comment: @stephan: updated the answer to reflect headers as well